# MySQL close timing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I write a class to load data and export as SMARTY format through MySQLi

```
public function myRow($sql)
{
    $this->connect();
    $rec = $this->conn->query($sql);
    $this->recordCount = $rec->num_rows;

    if ($this->makeRecordCount) {
        $this->totalRecordCount = $this->recordCount;
    }

    if ($this->recordCount > 0) {
        $names = array();
        $result = array();
        $temp = array();
        $count = $rec->field_count;

        // Get fields name
        while ($fields = mysqli_fetch_field($rec)) {
            $names[] = $fields->name;
        }

        while ($row = $rec->fetch_assoc()) {
            foreach ($names as $name) {
                $temp[$name] = $row[$name];
            }

            array_push($result, $temp);
        }
    } else {
        $result = null;
    }

    $this->conn->close();

    return $result;
}
```

Then I can to something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$datas = $class->myRow($sql);
$smarty->assign('datas', $datas);
```

There are maybe many data need to be loaded in one page, and I only want to connect to database once, but I want to do it all in class, I don't want to do something like

```
$class->connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$datas = $class->myRow($sql);
$smarty->assign('datas', $datas);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table2`";
$datas = $class->myRow($sql);
$smarty->assign('data2s', $data2s);
$class->close();
```

I feel it's ugly, but if I do this in class, that means I open and close connection when each data is loading, how to do it more beautiful?

Answer (score 1):

maybe i'm wrong but you don't need to force a mysql connection to close because of the fact that if the connection is not `persistent` the php `garbage collector` close all connections after the script execution.

so i suggest you not to force the mysql close, let the `garbage collector` handle this task and only close the connection by yourself if you're sure that no more mysql transactions are required.

Answer (score 1):

You simply don't need to (and shouldn't) open/close the connection inside your `myRow()` function.

Option 1 (naive approach): handle the connection at class level

```
class MyDAOClass {
    private static $connection = null;

    public function __construct() {
        if (self::$connection === null) {
             // establish connection here
        }
    }

    public function myRow(...) {
        // use self::$connection here
    }
}
```

Option 2:

Handle the connection from outside the class altogether (possibly in a singleton class), since all objects from your application probably can share the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Your second suggestion is what I would do.

```
$class->connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$datas = $class->myRow($sql);
$smarty->assign('datas', $datas);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table2`";
$datas = $class->myRow($sql);
$smarty->assign('data2s', $data2s);
$class->close();
```

You connect to the database once. As PHP is single threaded, you will load the first result, then go right away and load the second result. Once everything is done, you close the connection. No connection is kept alive longer than it has to, which is good.

What I usually do it make a method associated with Smarty that closes my database-connection too. That way I don't have to worry about closing it.

Something like this:

```
<?php
// Store reference to Smarty in Class
$class->setSmarty($smarty);

[...]

// Done with all database fetching, now display the template
$class->display('my_template.tpl');

[...]

// Example inplementation of the class
Class YourClass {
    private $smarty;
    public function setSmarty($smarty) {
        $this->smarty = &$smarty;
    }
    public function display($tpl) {
        $this->close();
        $this->smarty->display($tpl);
    }
}
?>
```